# Sort ASP.NET Dictionary

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dictionary

I want to bind a dictionary to DropDownList. But before binding
I want to sort it alphabetically - either by key or value.

How can I obtain that? Is there some kind of build in sort
function or a trick?

Here is my code:

```
      Dim Dic1 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

      Dic1.Add("1", "pear")
      Dic1.Add("2", "apple")
      Dic1.Add("3", "juice")
      Dic1.Add("4", "milk")
      Dic1.Add("5", "cornflakes")

    drpProduct.DataSource = Dic1
    drpProduct.DataTextField = "Value"
    drpProduct.DataValueField = "Key"
    drpProduct.DataBind()
```

Thanks in advance,
Best regards.

Comment: If you are getting the data from a database you could sort it when you read it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq:

```
drpProduct.DataSource = From kv In Dic1 Order By kv.Value
drpProduct.DataTextField = "Value"
drpProduct.DataValueField = "Key"
drpProduct.DataBind()
```

Change `Order By kv.Value` to `Order By kv.Key` if you want to order by the keys instead.

But as Adi has already mentioned, it is better to use a [`SortedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) from the start then.

Comment: Thaaaanks - that was so nice and easy :-) 

- Yes, if I could, I would sort the database records in the SQL.

Answer (score 3):

You could sort it yourself, but the best way to go is probably to use [`SortedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in LINQ by (e.g. to sort alphabetically on the key, C# syntax):

```
drpProduct.DataSource = Dic1.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key);
```

(VB.Net, something like `... = Dic1.OrderBy(Function(kvp) kvp.Key)`)

This doesn't inherently enforce an ordering on your dictionary, but it provides an ordering specifically when binding to the dropdown.

Comment: .OrderByDescending() can be used as well.